# NMHDR definition conflict?

Tags: winapi

in **richedit.h** NMHDR is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _nmhdr
{
    HWND    hwndFrom;
    UINT    idFrom;
    UINT    code;
} NMHDR;
```

in **winuser.h**, it is defined as :

```
typedef struct tagNMHDR
{
    HWND      hwndFrom;
    UINT_PTR  idFrom;
    UINT      code;         // NM_ code
}   NMHDR;
```

note that IdFrom went from being a UINT in richedit.h to a UINT_PTR in winuser.h

when compiling for 32bit that won't make a difference but, when compiling for 64bit, the winuser.h idFrom is going to be 4 bytes larger than the richedit.h idFrom.

I suspect that I must be missing something because a difference in size of 4 bytes between the two structures would have broken a fair amount of code out there but, I don't see how that conflict is resolved.

I would appreciate an explanation of how these two seemingly incompatible definitions can coexist.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Q: I would appreciate an explanation of how these two seemingly incompatible definitions can coexist.  A: "Stuff happens".  Here's some good information about the "Notification Message" (NM) header itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmheadera.  It looks like winuser.h is "right", and richedit.h is "wrong"...  I don't know when the "bug" was introduced into richedit.h, or if it was ever corrected.

Comment: In my default version of "Richedit.h" the definition is inside a `#ifndef WM_NOTIFY` block. Unlikely that it will ever be used in a real-world Windows build.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I noticed that too but, I figured that there might be a case out there where the richedit.h might be seen first by the compiler causing the definition to be different than the one in winuser.h.  Thank  you Adrian and thank you Paul for your answers.  It's good to know that the winuser.h version is the correct one (which is what I thought but, the confirmation is reassuring.)

Comment: @ScienceAmateur - even if you include *richedit.h* first - look at it begin - `#include <objbase.h>` exist. this mean that *objbase.h -> rpc.h -> windows.h -> winuser.h* will be included at begin. and `WM_NOTIFY` will be defined (if WINVER >= 0x0400) before `struct _nmhdr` conditional block - it can be compiled only for WINVER < 0x0400 (win 3.x ?)

Comment: @RbMm, I tried to follow the include chain but, I got lost in the process.  Thank you for unraveling that chain. :)

Comment: [`/showIncludes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=msvc-170) exist such compiler option. some time is very useful

Comment: @RbMm,  thank you for that tip and, indeed, that can sometimes be very useful (like for this case.)

Comment: I wonder (haven't tried) if #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN\n#include <richedit.h> would still draw winuser.h before richedit.h defines NMHDR.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir *winuser.h* unconditionally included from *windows.h*. `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` not affect this

Comment: Semantic detail but these are actually defining two differently named structures.